# How to write an allergy notice label?

Tags: expression, phrase-request

What is the correct expression, maybe some sort of a cliché, to warn consumers about possible allergens, something like:

> Don’t use this product if you have an allergy to one of its ingredients.

I tried to find such labels on the Internet but to no avail.

Comment: The main reason you won’t find this on the Internet is probably that, at least in my experience, such notices aren’t used in Germany (and probably no other German-speaking country), as you can still legally expect a minimum of common sense from your customers. What is rather done is that common allergenes are bold-faced in the lists of ingredients, so people with allergies can check quickly.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: they must be used by law on all pharmaceutical products (search for: *Gebrauchsinformation, Beipackzettel*).

Comment: @Takkat: I just read some random of these instructions from the Internet, and none even contained a word starting with *allerg,* let alone a comparable sentence. Even the sentences given in the answer or your comment to it are more specific.

Comment: Either way, as everybody has different assumptions about this: What kind of product are we talking about? Medication, food, cosmetics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical instruction leaflet reads as follows:

> (…)
>
> **2. Was müssen Sie vor der Einnahme von X-Tabletten beachten?**
>
> X-Tabletten dürfen nicht eingenommen werden
>
> (…)
>
> – wenn Sie **allergisch** (überempfindlich) gegen X sind.
>
> – wenn Sie **allergisch** gegen einen der sonstigen Bestandteile von X-Tabletten sind (siehe Abschnitt …).
>
> (…)

Comment: The standardized text for a patient's imformation is: *"wenn Sie **überempfindlich** (allergisch) **gegenüber** NAME oder einem der sonstigen Bestandteile von NAME sind;"*. Source: [BfArM](http://www.bfarm.de/)

Comment: The text or translation is about a  herbal bath. I think I will use your above sentence "wenn Sie allergisch gegenüber...". Thanks a lot for the help.